# Jackson JSON + Java Generics

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize/map the below JSON to `List<Bill`> java object using **Jackson json library**. (this json was generated by jackson, Iam omitting that piece for brevity)

```
{"bills":[{"amount":"13","billId":"billid3"}]}
```

Here is my conversion method:

```
private static void convert(){
   String jsonBill =  "{\"bills\":[{\"amount\":\"13\",\"billId\":\"billid3\"}]}";

   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   List<Bill> bills = null;
   try {
       bills = mapper.readValue(jsonBill, new TypeReference<List<Bill>>() { });
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   System.out.println("bills = " + bills.size());
}
```

The Bill entity is below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public class Bill { 
   private String amount;
   private String billId;

   public String getBillId() {
       return billId;
   }
   public void setBillId(String billId) {
       this.billId = billId;
   }
   public String getAmount() {
       return amount;
   }
   public void setAmount(String amount) {
       this.amount = amount;
   } 
}
```

and I get this error:

```
**org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7a84e4; line: 1, column: 1]**
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:160)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:194)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:103)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:93)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1980)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1278)
```

Here is my simplified spring3 controller which returns the i/p json (with Jackson mapping configured as default view):

```
@ModelAttribute("bills")
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Bill> fetchBills() throws IOException {
    Bill bill = new Bill();
    bill.setAmount("13");
    bill.setBillId("billid3");

    List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<Bill>();
    bills.add(bill);
    return bills;
}
```

I guess I am missing something obvious.. but not sure what it is.. Any ideas?

Comment: You're not telling it to map the attribute 'bills' to the billLst List. I've never done this directly (Spring 3.0 does it automagically), but I would expect to see a reference to the attribute 'bills'.

Comment: Yes that was a typo on my part - updated my post. Thanks. But the problem still exists..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem lies not in your code, but your example input.  What you're actually trying to deserialize is an object with a field named "bills", not a list!  What you should be using as input is:

```
[{"billId":"billid3","amount":"13"}]
```

This is an array of objects, which is converted to a list.

Comment: ahh.. Thanks for the pointer. I am using spring3 + Jackson Mapper and the json i/p I used was returned by the controller.

Comment: So I need to convert {"bills":[{"amount":"13","billId":"billid3"}]} to  [{"billId":"billid3","amount":"13"}] at my client side.  I am looking for Jackson wrapper method that let me do that without any custom code.

Comment: Ah, I've got no experience with Spring+Jackson, so I can't offer any more insight. Best of luck with it!

Comment: Wrapper should be trivial: just create simple POJO like:

public class Wrapper {
  List<Bill> bills;
}

and pass 'Wrapper.class' as type for readValue() method/

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing any custom code (like a dummy wrapper) if possible. But I'll live it for now. Thanks StaxMan.

Comment: That wrapper bean is part of your object model: model must match the JSON structure, so if you want to wrap your bills in "bills", it is needed. But do you really want that '"bills": [...]' part anyway? Why not just handle plain List and forget bogus property and wrapper? There is no need to add such an extra level if all you need is a List.

Comment: so this is the real answer, tough! :D nice one... @Jason Nichols

Answer (score 3):

Try using ObjectWriter instead of ObjectMapper

```
Writer writer=new StringWriter();

        ObjectWriter oWriter=om.writerWithType(new TypeReference<List<Bill>>() {
        });
        oWriter.writeValue(writer, result);
```

I'm using jackson 1.9.2