# Warning with List<String> on Android

Tags: java, android, string, list, warnings

I want to solve this warning. In this part of code i have this warning: `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<String>`

```
String preferences = pPrefs.getString(SharedPreferences);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                byte[] byteTemp = mapper.readValue(preferences, byte[].class);
                ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteTemp);
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    List<String> numbers = (List<String>) is.readObject();
```

How can i do? Thank you to all.

Comment: `Object` is the top level class. You are trying to cast an `Object` that can be any kind of object. You also dont provide much information so I'm assuming this is your problem.

Comment: I use the jackson library (json processor) to save and load my object into files. The object that i'm trying to load is a list<string>, so i don't undestard this error.

Comment: Post your method's code.

Comment: You say you're using jackson, but this is just using a plain old Java `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: I don't write all plain but just a little part.

Comment: Why are you storing a `byte[]` in the `SharedPreferences` and then getting it back as a `byte[]` and reading objects from it? It seems like you're undermining the way Jackson is intended to work. I'm not experienced with it, but see these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521601/jackson-serialization-with-objectmapper-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446514/jackson-json-java-generics

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectInputStream::readObject` returns an `Object`.

[readObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject())

You are casting it to a `List<String>` without first checking if it really is a `List<String>`. As far as the compiler knows, it can be any kind of `Object` (a `String`, an `Integer`, and so on...)

Comment: Whether or not you first check (which wouldn't be a bad idea), the compiler is still going to issue a warning on the cast. The only real alternative is to suppress the warning.

Comment: Yup, that's true. I was just explaining why the reason for this warning.

Comment: It will be up to the compiler. In your shoes, I would first check if the returned `Object` is an instace of a `List<String>`. The approach from user drakej is a good approach to accomplish that. Then if the warning is still present I would suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to fix this is to verify that is a List, then check all elements to determine if they are strings.

```
Object objs = is.readObject();

if (objs instanceof List) {
   List<Object> listObj = (List<Object>)objs;

   boolean result = true;
   for (Object o : listObj) {
       result &= o instanceof String;
   }

   if (result) return (List<String>)listObj;

}
```

No guarantee this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you think an `Object` is a `List<String>` there is no way to cast it to a `List<String>` without generating a warning because at runtime it is only possible to tell if the object is a `List`. You could however write a method that returns a `List<String>`which is a copy of the `Object`. Something like this would work. It returns `null` if the copy cannot be made.

```
static List<String> copy(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof List)) {
        return null;
    }
    List<?> list = (List) object;
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object ob : list) {
        if (ob instanceof String) {
            temp.add((String) ob);
        } else if (ob == null) {
            temp.add(null);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```